# Derivative of $ f(x) = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{c}} $?

Tags: calculus

> Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to take the derivative of this function:
>   $$ f(x) = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{c}} $$

Thank you

Comment: Where is $x$ in the definition of $f(x)$? Where is $x^3$?

Comment: @MathLover Maybe its constant w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Sorry fixed it, r should be x

Comment: Well, at any rate, please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Comment: split into cases according to sign of $x$.

Comment: @Raffaele Don't forget to use `&` to space/align.

Comment: @Raffaele Try this instead: `\text{sgn}(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}  -1&\text{if} \;x<0 \\  0& \text{if} \;x=0 \\ 1& \text{if} \;x>0 \\ \end{array} \right.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x\ge 0$ you have $f(x)=\dfrac{2\pi\,x}{\sqrt c}\to f'(x)=\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt c}$

when $x<0$ then $f(x)=.\dfrac{2\pi\,x}{\sqrt c}\to f'(x)=-\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt c}$

To put all together in one formula
$$f'(x)=\frac{2 \pi \, \text{sgn}(x)}{\sqrt{c}}$$
where $\text{sgn}(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{rr}
 -1&\text{if}\;x<0 \\
 0& \text{if} \;x=0 \\
1& \text{if} \;x>0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 2\pi\sqrt\frac{x^2}{c}$

$f'(x) = 2\pi*\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{c}}}*({\frac{x^2}{c}})'=2\pi\frac{\frac{x}{c}}{\sqrt\frac{x^2}{c}}=2\pi*\frac{\sqrt\frac{x^2}{c}}{x}$